# D3.js Tree pass node.name on click to R Shiny

Tags: jquery, r, node.js, d3.js, shiny

I would like first to address my intentions

1) Create a predefined D3.js collapsible Tree in Shiny

2) On click of a node the name of this specific node is passed from D3.js to R for further operations.

Well, at this moment I have a predefined D3.js collapsible tree in Shiny. I provide the code for js, server.R and ui.R below. Now at this point, I just have a interactive graphic, but I would like to go one step further.

As soon as I click on a node, I would like to get the name of the node as a variable.

I did my research (mainly here: https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/SearchTree), so I know, that I have to use d3OutputBinding to create a new variable. Further I found out, that

```
 .on('click', function(node) {
          alert(node.name);
```

would at least pop up a message with the nodes name. So I assume, I have to use something like

```
var d3OutputBinding = new Shiny.OutputBinding();
$.extend(d3OutputBinding, {
    find: function(scope) {
        return $(scope).find('.div_tree2');
    },
    renderValue: function(el) {
        var svg = d3.select(el).select("svg");
...
function update(source) {
...
nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
.on('click', function(node) {var nodes1 = node.name; });
...
Shiny.onInputChange(".nodesData", JSON.decycle(nodes1));
...
} // end of renderValue
}); // end of .extend
```

And plug it into server.R via reactive function (input$.nodesData).

Unfortunately, I am too dumb to achieve this. So I am kindly asking you for any advice.

As already stated, I would provide my codes. Here goes my d3script_tree.js

```
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsondata_tree",
  function(message){
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Parent",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "A",
        "parent": "Parent"
      },
      {
        "name": "B",
        "parent": "Parent"
        }
    ]
  }
];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("#div_tree2").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");


function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
/*   var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); })
 */ 
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); })

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      //.on("click", click);
      .on('click', function(node) {
      alert(node.name);
  });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function (d) { return '#05415A'; })
      //.style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "#C00000" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("link")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px");    

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", function (d) { return '#05415A'; })
     // .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "#C00000" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  nodeUpdate.select("link")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px");

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);


  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
  });
```

Next I have ui.R referencing to it. The CSS styles aren't of any importance, so it could be ignored.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Toy example", tabName = "toy", icon = icon("cog"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
  ),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "toy",
            tags$div(class="d3-div",
                     #to style to d3 output pull in css
                     tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css")),
                     #load D3JS library
                     tags$script(src="d3.min.js"),
                     #tags$script(src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"),
                     #load javascript
                     tags$script(src="d3script_tree.js"),
                     #create div referring to div in the d3script
                     tags$div(id="div_tree2"))
            )
  )
)

# Put them together into a dashboardPage
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Toy Example"),
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

And finally, there is server.R to trigger this Java script.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2, shiny.usecairo=T)

  var_json_tree <- toJSON(1, pretty = T)
  #push data into d3script
  session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsondata_tree",var_json_tree)  
})
```

Comment: While trying to reproduce: When i c&p your js code I get errors on lines 72, 152 and 162. Do you intend to close the message handler on line 72?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you need the `Shiny.OutputBinding();` part for this, you can just use `Shiny.onInputChange` to pass the node name back to the `server.R`.

I didn't run your whole code but you could try:

```
.on('click', function(node) {
          Shiny.onInputChange("node_name", node.name);
}
```

And in `server.R`, `input$node_name` will hold the name of the node.

EDIT

To keep the collapsing tree, you can just edit the `click` function at the end of your javascript:

```
function click(d) {
  Shiny.onInputChange("node_name", d.name);
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
  });
```

Comment: Perfect! Also it is possible to create multiple variables, like parent.name and pass them through.

Comment: Sorry but now I have another problem: since I have deleted `.on('click', click)` my tree is not collapsible anymore :(. Simply adding it in the `function(node)` does not help. I've tried to add another `.on('click', click)` but this did not do the trick

Comment: Add the end of your javascript, there is a function called `function click(d)`. Paste the code from that function in your new one. Make sure your replace `d` by `node` as well. or add the Shiny.onInputChange directly to it